# alert if screen width is less then a specified size

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Ruby on Rails v6 application.

What I need to achieve is to send an alert to the user when it connect to the application, if the screen width is less than 1000px.

I found several suggestions, my preferred is

```
$(window).onload(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width < 1000){
    alert('Your screen is too small');
  }
});
```

The only problem is that I don't know where to place it:

My application controller calls `application.html.haml` page and not `application.js.erb` page, so, where can I put that code fragment?

Comment: Your `application.html` should probably include your `application.js` file. Just be sure to only put JavaScript that is needed on every page in `application.js` to keep page load times down.

Comment: Scott, can you give me a sample on how to include application.js in application.html and the content of application.js? Thank you

Comment: The link I provided in my answer has all of those things. If it's not clear and you'd like guidance on your project specifically, add your `application.js` and `application.html` code snippets to your question and I can comment on what might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the problem. I just changed `$(window).onload` with `$(document).ready` and the alert magically appeared!

Thank you to everybody.

Comment: Good luck Paolo

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the **:javascript** filter to add javascript codes inline:
>
> And the following code should be placed after your jQuery include tag.
>   I suggest placing it at the end of the body.

```
:javascript
    $(window).onload(function () {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 1000) {
            alert('Your screen is too small');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I  placed it at the end of the code (exactly, at t he end of the body) but it is not fired when I started the application

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid inline JS whenever possible as doing so means you're not taking advantage of the benefits of Webpack.

If this code isn't used everywhere, but only on a specific page, I would just create a new pack (in `app/javascript/packs`), and include it on the page where it's needed with the `javascript_pack_tag` helper.

If it is used on every page, then just create the new pack and then require it in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`.

Here's a link to an article that demonstrates these two approaches: https://dev.to/morinoko/adding-custom-javascript-in-rails-6-1ke6